# Numerical Computation of Linbald Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, numerical-method

Can anybody suggest me a good algorithm for the time evolution of the reduced density matrix using Linbald equation. My Hamiltonian is time dependent. I am aware about Qotoolbox and Qutip. I have checked both things but I don't have any clues about the algorithms they are using. I have to find the entanglement dynamics in a bipartite system under dissipation and forcing.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing - do you want to know what algorithms there are *besides* Qotoolbox and Qutip, *what* algorithms these two are using, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

In qutip we use use the scipy ode solvers and in particular the 12th order Adams-Bashforth method via zvode. Solving for the evolution of the density matrix is just a standard ode equation provided that you pick a basis representation to express the Liouvillian in matrix form,  and the density matrix as a column vector by stacking the matrix columns, for example. However, any ode solving package will work. Depending on the language that you use, you might also have to represent complex numbers using two real floats.

Comment: The question is?